# Output hbs templates as usable HTML in Webpack

Tags: webpack, handlebars.js

I'm trying to make a new webpack project in which I can create my frontend files with Handlebars and Sass. The way I (sometimes) use this is by sending a client a zipfile with a compiled project. i.e: index.html + contact.html and some injected CSS etc.

Just plain ol' HTML but with the advantages of using partials etc.

So I'm setting up a new Webpack project and I have it working properly. It compiles my test.hbs file and shows it on my localhost environment(webpack dev server). It reloads fine and even the partials work fine.

However, the one thing that I still need from Handlebars is a way to actually *save* the root level hbs files (app/src/{file}.hbs) to HTML files. So I can zip and send them for example.

My Webpack knowledge is pretty basic so I'm not aware if I can use a plugin or something to solve this.

I have a single `index.html` file in my dist folder that loads my `main.js`. And IN that file my `test.hbs` file is shown now. I would be happy(ier) if I'd get a list of all my compiled templates in my index.html with a `{url}/contact.html` type of url structure.

Any ideas are welcome!!

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 9000
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.hbs$/, loader: "handlebars-loader" },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Test 123',
      template: './app/src/test.hbs'
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Webpack doesn't sound like the right tool to me because it is a JavaScript bundler and, if I understand correctly, you don't want to bundle any JavaScript - you just want to create static HTML files from Handlebars templates.

Comment: A quick Google search produces this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-webpack-plugin. It might be useful.